# "readOnly" and other symbols not found when executing shell script remotely

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, ssh

I have a simple shell script below :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Hadoop Clear
readOnly hadoop = /opt/hadoop/bin/hadoop
hadoop fs -rm -r /
```

When I run the script in the terminal of the same machine, everything works without error.
Now, I want to invoke this script remotely. So from my `java` program, I do an `ssh` to the server,  and invoke the script as :
`sh <full Path to script>`.

I get an error saying:

```
clearHadoop.sh: readOnly: not found
clearHadoop.sh: hadoop not found
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I first run the shell script on machine A. It works. Then I run the same script on the same machine A but I invoke the script from machine B. There is hadoop in A and readOnly is a a shell keyword, so I don't think that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readonly` is a bash keyword, not `readOnly`.

This sounds like you are adding the path to `hadoop` to `$PATH` in a shell init file that only affects interactive sessions (and so not remote sessions).

Also `sh` is not `/bin/bash`. If you want `bash` use `bash` and not `sh`.

Comment: Where do I need to add the path to enable it in  remote sessions ?

Comment: Info would be helpful, but I solved the issue temporarily by giving full path to hadoop.

Comment: @Aneesh Where are you adding it now? Shell init files are somewhat complicated to understand. There are a few really good answers about them on the stackexchange sites (but I'm having trouble finding them at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your readOnly line. At least the bash's that I just tried al complained about read**O**nly